# Google Glass preview image scrambled with new XE10 release

Tags: google-glass

This occurs using a few apks that make use of the camera (e.g., zxing, opencv).  It displays a glitched image in the preview but it is still a function of what the camera sees so it appears to be an encoding mismatch.  The native camera preview works fine, so the internal apps do not exhibit this problem.

Comment: This bug still exists as of XE12.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For now, please try adding the following workaround after you acquire the `Camera` but before you setup and start the preview:

```
Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
params.setPreviewFpsRange(30000, 30000);
camera.setParameters(params);
```

(Or just add the `setPreviewFpsRange` call to your existing parameters if you're setting others as well.)

Comment: 30FPS seems a bit too high. I recommend something lower, 5FPS, especially for a battery hungry device like Glass.

Answer (score 8):

For anyone using ZXing on their Glass, you can build a version from the source code with the above fix.

Add the following method into CameraConfigurationManager.java

```
  public void googleGlassXE10WorkAround(Camera mCamera) {
        Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        params.setPreviewFpsRange(30000, 30000);
        params.setPreviewSize(640,360);
        mCamera.setParameters(params);
  }
```

And call this method immediately after anywhere you see Camera.setParameters() in the ZXing code. I just put it in two places in the CameraConfigurationManager and it worked.

I set the Preview Size to be 640x360 to match the Glass resolution.

Comment: 30FPS seems to be a lot, and the 640x360 preview size is not needed to fix the problem. The problem was the default FPS was too high at 60FPS. See my answer below...

Answer (score 4):

30 FPS preview is pretty high. If you want to save some battery and CPU, consider the slowest supported FPS to be sufficient:

```
List<int[]> supportedPreviewFpsRanges = parameters.getSupportedPreviewFpsRange();
int[] minimumPreviewFpsRange = supportedPreviewFpsRanges.get(0);
parameters.setPreviewFpsRange(minimumPreviewFpsRange[0], minimumPreviewFpsRange[1]);
```

Comment: I don't know why someone voted this down.  
This is fact the exact code that ZXing accepted as a Pull Request from me to fix the problem:  
https://github.com/zxing/zxing/commit/9e08da655eb6d5423b286f83aa356230536b13a5

Comment: Works for me. Best answer here IMO.

Answer (score 1):

The bug still exists as of XE16 and XE16.11 but this code gets past the glitch and shows a normal camera preview, note the three parameter setting lines and their values.  I have also tested this at 5000 (5FPS) and it works, and at 60000 (60FPS) and it does not work:

```
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        if (mCamera == null) return;

        Camera.Parameters camParameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        camParameters.setPreviewFpsRange(30000, 30000);
        camParameters.setPreviewSize(1920, 1080);
        camParameters.setPictureSize(2592, 1944);
        mCamera.setParameters(camParameters);
        try {
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you change zxing lib? What class did you put this code inside? Could you show more? In my implementation I don't have access to the camera class...

Answer (score 0):

This still is an issue as of XE22 (!) Lowering the frames per second to 30 or lower does the trick:

```
 parameters.setPreviewFpsRange(30000, 30000);
```

And indeed, don't forget to set the parameters:

```
camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

I have found no clear explanation as to why this causes trouble, since 60 fps is included in the supported fps range. The video can record 720p, but I never saw a source add the fps to this.

Answer (score -2):

You can set the `params.setPreviewSize(1200,800)`. You can change the values around this range until you can clear color noise.

Comment: This does not fix the problem.