# Google Glass import Zxing

Tags: import, zxing, google-glass

cheers,

we got our hands on one exemplar of the google glass and trying out a little bit. We wanted to create a Barcode Scanner using the zxing library.

We imported these two classes: https://github.com/zxing/zxing/tree/master/android-integration/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/integration/android

and start the intent via:

```
    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(MainActivity.this);
    integrator.initiateScan();
```

but we get a scrambled camera image, like here:
[Glass camera preview display is garbled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20557686/glass-camera-preview-display-is-garbled)

We tried several fixes but were unable to import the zxing library to work with our project.

Best
zxing/zxing
github.com

Answer (score 0):

The BarcodeEye seems to have resolved this problem in their port of ZXing:

https://github.com/BarcodeEye/BarcodeEye

I used the above code as a base and abstracted some of the code into a Android library, if that helps:

https://github.com/jaxbot/glass-barcode